# Check whether there is any synonyms between two word sets

Tags: python, nltk

I need to find the synonyms for a given word from a sentence. For an example

```
list1 = ['happy']
list2 = ['It', 'is', 'so', 'funny']
```

Here I need to find whether there is any synonyms for 'happy' word from list2 and print them. I'am new to the Python. I tried it from following code.

```
from nltk.corpus import wordnet
list1 = ['happy']
list2 = ['It', 'is', 'so', 'funny']
list = []

for word1 in list1:
 for word2 in list2:
    wordFromList1 = wordnet.synsets(word1)
    wordFromList2 = wordnet.synsets(word2)
    if wordFromList1 and wordFromList2:
       s = wordFromList1[0].word1.lemmas(wordFromList2[0])
       s = wordFromList1[0].word2.lemmas(wordFromList2[0])
    list.append(s)

    print((list))
```

But it does not work. Please help me.

Comment: I suspect that `wordFromList1 and wordFromList2` doesn't do what you expect it to.  If `wordnet.synsets(word1)` is a set of synonyms, shouldn't you make a set containing all the synonyms for all the words in list1 and then check each word in list2 against it?

Comment: Also don't use the name `list`, it shadows the built-in `list` function

Comment: @PatrickHaugh. Yes I need to make a set containing all the synonyms for all the words in list1 and check each word in list2 against it. can you tell me how should it do.

Comment: Assuming these are python sets, you can do `set.union(wordnet.synsets(word) for word in list1)`

Comment: Could you rewrite the code with the correct way. I'am new to the Python and not much familiar. Please help me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you use `wordnet.synsets("happy")` it returns synset entries (such as Synset('happy.a.01')) that contains part of speech info and an ID. You need to use `lemma_names()` on this to get the actual word forms. Try this:

```
from nltk.corpus import wordnet

def get_word_synonyms_from_sent(word, sent):
    word_synonyms = []
    for synset in wordnet.synsets(word):
        for lemma in synset.lemma_names():
            if lemma in sent and lemma != word:
                word_synonyms.append(lemma)
    return word_synonyms

word = "happy"
sent = ['I', 'am', 'glad', 'it', 'was', 'felicitous', '.']
word_synonyms = get_word_synonyms_from_sent(word, sent)
print ("WORD:", word)
print ("SENTENCE:", sent)
print ("SYNONYMS FOR '" + word.upper() + "' FOUND IN THE SENTENCE: " + ", ".join(word_synonyms))

# OUTPUT
# >>> WORD: happy
# >>> SENTENCE: ['I', 'am', 'glad', 'it', 'was', 'felicitous', '.']
# >>> SYNONYMS FOR 'HAPPY' FOUND IN THE SENTENCE: felicitous, glad
```

Comment: This was exactly what I needed. Thank you so much @PrettyHands

Comment: No problem, I'm glad it works for you. Just be aware of the limitations of WordNet - I would have expected to see words such as 'jolly' and 'upbeat' as synonyms, but they're missing.

Comment: can I add a score if there is any synonyms to happy in considered sentence. For an example, there are two synonyms in  sentence for happy which are glad and felicitous. Can I add a score for that two synonyms like 1,1 total score = 2.

Comment: The 'score' for happy would be `len(word_synonyms)`.The NLTK book ( http://www.nltk.org/book/ ) is a great help for familiarizing yourself with Python and NLP :)

Comment: Currently I'am working on a project which is emotions detecting (happy,sad etc) from text in a chat application using Python and NLTK. I'am not much familiar with NLP and Python. As a basic way, I hope to use keyword based method. In that case I have to make a emotional keyword list under each emotional state and need to find whether there is any emotional keyword in given sentence and identify the relevant emotional state accordingly. So what I need here to know, do I need to create a training data set and feature list to do that task, If yes, how can I do it.

Comment: I've not done any sentiment analysis myself, but there's a How To here: http://www.nltk.org/howto/sentiment.html

I'd recommend you search online for sentiment analysis and then ask any further questions you may have as new questions. Good luck!

Comment: Thank you. I will.